# Вывод списка категорий WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Разбираюсь в движке, не понятна одна вещь. 
Есть три категории к которым относятся определенные записи. 
На странице вывода записей пытаюсь вывести список категорий со ссылками на них. Этот же код будет присутствовать и на шаблоне вывода рубрик category.php, с тем лишь отличием, что на активной рубрике она должна исключаться из списка. Т.е на странице записей по идее должно отображаться 3 ссылки, а на странице рубрики 2.
На деле, уже на странице записей идет исключение одной рубрики. Почему так происходит и как этого избежать. Спасибо за ответы.

```
$single_category = get_the_category();                                    
$category_id = $single_category[0]->cat_ID;
$args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'category',
    'exclude' => $category_id
);

$categories = get_categories($args);
```

Comment: Поясните, почему вы считаете, что ` на странице записей по идее должно отображаться 3 ссылки, а на странице рубрики 2`. По какой такой идее? Вы же явно исключаете текущую категорию.

Comment: вот я и прошу разъяснить этот момент, не могу понять, почему на странице записей исключается категория

Comment: Если из 3х рубрик одна исключается - сколько останется?  (ида, рубрик, а не категорий)

Comment: `почему на странице записей исключается категория` - да потому что вы ее исключаете с помощью 'exclude' => $category_id